# Applet is not shown on a jsp on a spring web project

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, applet

I developing a spring mvc web project with spring security. I also developed a Java Applet, which works fine in the browser in an html file (the Applet is also signed with the jarsigner). Now I want to include it in an jsp file on the spring web project, so I used the tag as followed in the jsp file:

```jsp
<jsp:plugin type="applet" archive="MutualAuthentication.jar" 
    code="MutualAuthenticationHTTPApplet.class" codebase="." width="400" height="300">
</jsp:plugin>
```

I looked into the other examples but with no luck. Everything is running on a tomcat Server and the message tomcat is giving me is the following:

```
Jan 16, 2014 3:09:24 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet noHandlerFound
WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/tkey/MutualAuthentication.jar] in DispatcherServlet with name 'mvc-dispatcher'
Jan 16, 2014 3:09:24 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet noHandlerFound
WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/tkey/MutualAuthentication.jar] in DispatcherServlet with name 'mvc-dispatcher'
Jan 16, 2014 3:09:24 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet noHandlerFound
WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/tkey/MutualAuthentication.jar] in DispatcherServlet with name 'mvc-dispatcher'
Jan 16, 2014 3:09:24 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet noHandlerFound
WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/tkey/MutualAuthentication.jar] in DispatcherServlet with name 'mvc-dispatcher'
Jan 16, 2014 3:09:24 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet noHandlerFound
WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/tkey/MutualAuthenticationHTTPApplet.class] in DispatcherServlet with name 'mvc-dispatcher'
Jan 16, 2014 3:09:24 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet noHandlerFound
WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/tkey/MutualAuthenticationHTTPApplet/class.class] in DispatcherServlet with name 'mvc-dispatcher'
```

and my Applet is located in the following Location:

```
src    
    |--main
        |--webapp
            |--WEB-INF
                |--pages
                    |--*.jsp
                |--mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml
                |--spring-security.xml
                |--web.xml
            |--index.jsp
            |--MutualAuthentication.jar
```

I think it has something to do with the `DispatcherServlet` and the `Mapping`, but I can't get it in the right way.

So my question is, how can I include an Applet in an jsp on a spring mvc/security webProject?

Answer (score 0):

ok, i had the same problem... i've spent couple of hours of trying different combinations and this works for me:

put the YourAppletName.jar in the webapp/resources , be sure to have 
`<resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />` in your servlet-context

call the applet with:

```
<object type="application/x-java-applet" height="300" width="550">
<param name="code" value="<c:url value="your.package.name.YourAppletClass"/>" />
<param name="class" value="<c:url value="your.package.name.YourApplet.class"/>" />
<param name="archive" value="<c:url value="resources/YourAppletName.jar"/>"/>
Applet failed to run.  No Java plug-in was found.
</object>
```

hope this helps